# Check if array is monotonic i.e either monotone increasing or monotone decreasing

Tags: java, array

An array A is monotone increasing if for all i <= j, A[i] <= A[j].  An array A is monotone decreasing if for all i <= j, A[i] >= A[j].

Return true if and only if the given array A is monotonic.

```
public class MonotonicArray {

    public boolean IsMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
        if (numbers == null  || numbers.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (numbers.length == 1) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean increasing = false;
        boolean decreasing = false;

        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length - 1; index++) {

            if (numbers[index + 1] == numbers[index]){
                continue;
            }

            if (numbers[index + 1] > numbers[index]) {
                if (!decreasing) {
                    increasing = true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else  {
                if (!increasing) {
                    decreasing = true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }
        return increasing || decreasing;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
class MonotonicArrayTest extends MonotonicArray {

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic1() {

    int[] array =  new int[]{1,2,3};
   assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic2() {

    int[] array =  new int[]{-1,-2,-3};
    assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic3() {

    int[] array =  new int[]{1,2,1};
    assertEquals(false,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic4() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{-1,2,-9};
    assertEquals(false,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic5() {

    int[] array =  new int[]{9,3,2};
    assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic6() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{};
    assertEquals(false,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic7() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{1};
    assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}


@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic8() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{9,7,5,4,8,10};
    assertEquals(false,IsMonotonic(array));
}

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic9() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{1,1,2,3};
    assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isMonotonic10() {
    int[] array =  new int[]{1,1,0,-1};
    assertEquals(true,IsMonotonic(array));
}
```

}

Comment: It has bugs. Result for an empty array should be `true`. Result for an array of all-equal values should also be `true`.

Comment: @superbrain Can you justify why it should return true for the empty array? I am inclined to say that it should be UB or exception but I can't really make a solid argument about why that and not some other way...

Comment: @superbrain Do you base it on the fact that "for all (i,j) in an empty set" is always satisified?

Comment: @slepic Yes, that's why.

Comment: The real property is `forall i. A[i] <= A[i+1]` (or `>=` for decreasing). For an empty or singleton array, the domain of `i` is empty, so it property is vacuously satisfied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## static

`IsMonotonic(...)` does not need an instance of the `MonotonicArray` class to function, therefore it should be static.

## Consistency

You special case an array of length 1 as monotonic.  Is it really?  It is neither increasing nor decreasing.

What about `IsMonotonic(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1})`?  Seems to me that should be `true`, but it will return `false`.  Definitely should be added as a test case.  And if it should return `true`, then ...

## Optimization

... checking for length 1 is too restrictive.  Any length 2 array will always be monotonic as well.  Perhaps:

```
    if (numbers.length == 1) {
        return true;
    }
```

should be:

```
    if (numbers.length <= 2) {
        return true;
    }
```

## Looping

This is ugly.  Will Java optimize the `numbers.length - 1` calculation as a constant?

```
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length - 1; index++) {

        if (numbers[index + 1] == numbers[index]){
            continue;
        }
        ...
```

It may be better to use Java's enhanced `for` loop to extract numbers, and rely on monotonic behaviour allowing equality to handle the first element:

```
    int current = numbers[0];
    for(int value : numbers) {
        if (value != current) {
           if (value < current) {
              ...
           } else {
              ...
           }
           current = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To avoid nesting `if` statements, another minor improvement would be `if (value == current) continue;`

Comment: What? You don't think a length-1 array should be considered monotonic? To me, it sounds like it should definitely be considered monotonic.

Comment: “[An array of length 1] is neither increasing nor decreasing.” It is both.

Comment: The monotonicity property vacuously holds for a single-element array, because there is no second element to invalidate it.

Answer (score 5):

The loop is rather complicated. It is generally better to use simpler logic if possible, as that makes the loop simpler to reason about. For example, you can use `Integer.compare` to remove a lot of the logic from your loop.

```
public static boolean IsMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
    int lastCmp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(numbers[i], numbers[i - 1]);

        if (lastCmp == 0) {
            lastCmp = cmp;
        } else if (cmp != 0 && ((cmp > 0) != (lastCmp > 0))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In each iteration the `cmp` variable is zero if the two numbers are equal, and either positive or negative depending on whether there was an increase or decrease.

When `lastCmp` is zero, we have yet to see an increase or decrease, i.e. all integers have been equal. If `lastCmp` is nonzero, then we have seen either an increase or decrease. If the sequence is not monotonic, we will eventually reach a pair that moved in the opposite direction from the first change, which is what the second condition will detect.

If the list is shorter than two elements, then the loop doesn't run at all, and just returns true.

Comment: Due to integer overflow, `{ 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE }` would erroneously test as monotonic.

Comment: I fixed the integer overflow.

Comment: This new version might not work, as [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)) can return *any* positive or negative result. So your `-sign == lastSign` check isn't safe.

Comment: Interesting. I initially wrote out the three-way case, but my IDE said it could be replaced with `Integer.compare`. It's annoying that they don't guarantee this behaviour for integer comparison.

Comment: @superbrain What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's annoying. I think they really only return 0, 1 or -1, just don't guarantee it. I think your newest version is correct, but it was a little prettier before. I'm almost sorry I pointed this issue out :-)

Answer (score 4):

- You might get better performance and simplicity if you make up your mind right away: Comparing the *first* value with the *last* value immediately tells you which **one** of increasing/decreasing/constant you should check.
- What you should do for `null` depends on the contract. [This problem is on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/monotonic-array/), where you're even guaranteed that the array will have at least one element, so there you wouldn't need to cover `null` or an empty array. You "chose"(?) to return `false`, but you could just as well argue for `true`, since "no array" seems rather similar to "no elements", for which the correct answer is btw `true`, not `false`.

Here's one that uses a first-vs-last check (although I included "constant" in "increasing") and which puts the burden on the caller to provide a reasonable input (i.e., not `null`). I think it's better to have the user get an error than to silently pretend nothing's wrong.

```
    public boolean isMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
        int last = numbers.length - 1;
        if (last >= 0 && numbers[0] <= numbers[last]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] < numbers[i+1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

A `BiPredicate` version inspired by [RoToRa's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248181/228314). This one distinguishes all three cases, as the `BiPredicate` avoids code duplication:

```
    public boolean isMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
        int n = numbers.length;
        if (n <= 2) {
            return true;
        }
        BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> fail =
            numbers[0] < numbers[n-1] ? (a, b) -> a > b :
            numbers[0] > numbers[n-1] ? (a, b) -> a < b :
                                        (a, b) -> a != b;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (fail.test(numbers[i-1], numbers[i]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Python version, just for fun :-)

```
from operator import eq, le, ge

def isMonotonic(numbers):
    first, last = numbers[:1], numbers[-1:]
    check = eq if first == last else le if first < last else ge
    return all(map(check, numbers, numbers[1:]))
```

Comment: Your idea of looking at the last element to determine direction is interesting, but might touch a cache line that didn't need to be touched if the early part of the array is enough to prove it non-monotonic.  But is simplifies startup so either strategy could be better depending on the inputs.  (Assuming you're optimizing for speed, as discussed in [another comment thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248161/check-if-array-is-monotonic-i-e-either-monotone-increasing-or-monotone-decreasin#comment486094_248181).)  But yes, 2 separate loops in if/else is efficient and readable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, but it's only one cache-line. And the early-part argument is for best-case scenarios. I'm more interested in worst-case, i.e., where times matter more. Like very long arrays that *are* monotonic. I don't care much about super-duper-fast vs "just" super-fast in best-case scenarios :-)

Comment: It's only one cache line, but if it's cold in cache that could stall the pipeline for long enough that it could have already finished looking at the first few cache lines of the array. I'm picturing a case where the first few cache lines of the array are hot in cache, but the end isn't.  (Although if it was just written first to last, that's opposite). The separate loops only have a control dependency, not a data dependency, on that last line, so if the branch predicted correctly all that work can be already done under the latency of that cache miss.  But if it mispredicts, it has to restart.

Comment: Agreed for most cases it's fine, and doesn't impact the worst-case large monotonic array time by more than a couple hundred clock cycles in the worst case, negligible compared to the difference between SIMD and scalar code for this, especially on x86 where branching on SIMD compare results can be done efficiently.  (Unlike on some ARM)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a big fan of having a single monolithic function that indiscriminately checks for both increasing and decreasing monotony. In most practical scenarios I would imagine you'd probably need to know if it's increasing or decreasing.

Based on that I'd specifically define:

```
public static boolean isMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
   return isMonotonicIncreasing(numbers) || isMonotonicDecreasing(numbers);
}

public static boolean isMonotonicIncreasing(int[] numbers) {
   return isXXX(numbers, (a, b) -> a <= b); // Not sure how to call this method
}
```

Sure, there will be a couple of duplicate checks, but in the end IMO the code will be better structured, better readable and more re-usable.

Comment: Regarding the function name: as the second parameter is a `BiPredicate` and predicates use the standard method name `test()`, I'd go for `pairwiseTest(int[] numbers. BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> predicate)` or - moving away from the primitives `<T> pairwiseTest(List<T> objects, BiPredicate<T, T> predicate)`.

Comment: Re "a couple of duplicate checks": on most inputs one or the other will indeed bail out quickly, but in the worst case it's twice the number of checks, for example 111111111111110.

Comment: @Thomas Well the OP's solution has up to *three* checks at every element, while this has at worst two. (But yes, it's worse than the optimal solution, which only needs *one* check at every element.)

Comment: I combined our answers to [this](https://repl.it/repls/RawFatalSearch#Main.java). Do you see a way to make that nicer? (I'm not much of a Java guy.)

Comment: @superbrain: If you were serious about optimizing this for speed *without* a lot of care for keeping the source compact, you'd probably start by scanning for an element not equal to the first element (can be done very efficiently with SIMD), then depending on that one compare, enter one of two loops that only check for a single ordering.  (Hard to vectorize with SIMD, but cheap with scalar so should compile to a loop with just a couple asm instructions that hopefully checks 1 element per clock cycle.)  So one loop to start, possible early return, then if/else with a loop in each branch.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ugh... I wrote a lot of assembly in the '90s for years. Not going back to that ever again :-). Or do you mean the Java compiler would do it with SIMD for me? In any case, I like your start+branch idea, although I don't like the extra code for the start loop and I doubt it'll make a noteworthy difference in slow cases (like very long monotonic arrays) compared to my first-vs-last approach (unless you do get SIMD and the equality-prefix is long as well).

Comment: @superbrain: A JIT might possible auto-vectorize the search-for-equal loop, but I wouldn't count on it.  I think there is some limited HotSpot auto-vectorization for simple cases.  If you wanted to manually vectorize this, you'd use C++ with intrinsics like `_mm_cmpeq_epi32` for that first loop (or experimental ISO C++ `std::simd`).  The 2nd loop isn't as bad as I thought; you just need to compare each element to the next separately, not every combination, so that's just one load + 1 unaligned `_mm_loadu_si128` to feed `_mm_cmpgt_epi32`.  (Or aligned loads + `_mm_alignr_epi8`)

Comment: @superbrain: Writing asm by hand is a terrible idea for almost every case, except sometimes for ARM because for some reason compilers are worse with ARM NEON intrinsics than with x86 SSE or PowerPC AltiVec.  The initial loop is probably only has minor value since it turns out it should be possible to fairly efficiently vectorize a single-direction monotonicity check, mostly just avoiding touching the last element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112049/discussion-between-superb-rain-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the **consistency** remark of @AJNeufeld (so that `[1]` being monotonic indicates that `[1,1,1]` may rather be monotonic too) and put the other remark about `[x,y]` being monotonic again, you may find it easier to have `true`-s by default and recognize when the array is not monotonic:

```
public static boolean IsMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean inc_or_const = true;
    boolean dec_or_const = true;
    int prev = numbers[0];
    for (int curr : numbers) {
        if (curr < prev) {
            inc_or_const = false;
        } else if (curr > prev) {
            dec_or_const = false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return inc_or_const || dec_or_const;
}
```

Of course it looks that tidy only without short-circuiting, after that this will have a very similar structure to your original code again:

```
public static boolean IsMonotonic(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean inc_or_const = true;
    boolean dec_or_const = true;
    int prev = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int curr = numbers[i];
        if (curr < prev) {
            inc_or_const = false;
            if (!dec_or_const) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (curr > prev) {
            dec_or_const = false;
            if (!inc_or_const) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here I went back to indexed access on the basis of my dislike against comparing the first element to itself (what the `for(:)` variant does). Also note that here, because of the short-circuit `return`s, completion of the loop means that the array is monotonic for sure. Plus the remark about the hazard of having `numbers.length-1` in the loop condition has been applied too.